# How to enable check box which is in 2nd column with reference to name in 1 st column?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

No having a source code: this is an interview question.
Example:

```
S.no    Column 1         column 2
1        abc             checkbox
2        xyz             checkbox
```

Now i need to enable checkbox with reference to name in column 1.
How can we achieve this in selenium ?

Thanks

Comment: can you share html?

Comment: it would be great  if you can share the HTML

Comment: “It would be great” meaning there’s no real way to answer your question without source HTML or the url of the page in question.

Comment: This is an interview question.

Answer (score 0):

Select the suitable following sibling relative to the known node by xpath-axes `following-sibling` and click on it.
Example:

source-code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>S.no</td>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>xyz</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

expression:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'abc')]/following-sibling::td/input[@type='checkbox']")).click();`